# Laravel Thujohn Twitter bad authentication error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to post on Twitter from my website, but I am getting the below error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
[215] Bad Authentication data.
```

I want to know how to perform authentication for Twitter.

I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: Welcome. Are you using any third party Twitter libraries? If so, please post them (in your question) and show us how you post to Twitter.

Comment: Please make sure your issue is reproducible for anyone who sees only your post, otherwise it's unlikely to get any help. See also [mcve]. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's latest API 1.1 does not allow access without authentication

check this

> https://tomelliott.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth

Comment: Thanks for this.
That i know, my question is how to do authentication ?

Comment: @prashant create consumer secret and consumer key for authentication